# How to get alternative line from a file and store it as string into a struct?

Tags: c, string, file, struct, io

i have a file needed to be read by code. The file is shown as below. The very ﬁrst line of the ﬁle contains a single integer, indicating the number of journal entries in the ﬁle. I need to write a C program to read a ﬁle and store the contents in a dynamically-allocated array of structs.

```
4
12/04/2010 
Interview went well I think, though was told to wear shoes. 
18/04/2010 
Doc advised me to concentrate on something... I forget. 
03/05/2010
Was asked today if I was an art exhibit. 
19/05/2010 
Apparently mudcakes not made of mud, or angry wasps.
```

I was able to strtok() the day, month and year to store in my struct, however I am stuck in saving the strings to my structs.
Here is my code for strtok(),

```
FILE* file=fopen("struct.txt","r");
        if (file==NULL){
            perror("Error opening file\n.");}
            else {
                fscanf(file,"%d",&size);
                 res=(Diary*)malloc(size*sizeof(Diary));
                 fscanf(file,"%*[^\n]");
while(fgets(day,1024,file)!= NULL){
    oken=strtok(day,"/");
    h[i]=atoi(oken);          */h[i] is my day
    oken=strtok(NULL,"/");
    fre[i]=atoi(oken);        */fre[i] is the month
    oken=strtok(NULL,"/");
    re[i]=atoi(oken);          */ re[i] is the year
    okena=strtok(day,"\n");
    strcpy(rese[i],okena);    */i had declared rese as char rese[1024]
    printf("%s",okena);
    i++;
   }
```

the program is not working with that strcpy(), when i run it, it keep crashing. However if i remove the strcpy(), it will print as follow:

```
12
Interview went well I think, though was told to wear shoes. 
18
Doc advised me to concentrate on something... I forget. 
03
Was asked today if I was an art exhibit. 
19
Apparently mudcakes not made of mud, or angry wasps.
```

which this is not the strings i want to store in my struct as well. I am stuck in how to store the strings into a struct. My struct is

```
typedef struct journal{
int day;
int month;
int year;
char entry[1024];
} Diary;
```

Any good souls could tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Have *two* `fgets` calls? One for the date-line, and one for the "entry"-line.

Comment: What is `h` in `h[i]=atoi(oken);`? Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: if i do that, where should i store the date-line and entry-line to? i tried to used fgets for date and entry, then continue with another fgets (which is the code above), i lost all my day, month and year

Comment: h is an array of int, to store the day from the file.

Comment: @sterstar show a [mcve]. It's hard to help with that little information.

Comment: `char date[20], entry[1024]; while (fgets(date, sizeof date, file) != NULL && fgets(entry, sizeof entry, file) != NULL) { ... }`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if i am using two fgets like what you have shown me, i can only get until entry number three, which the last entry is not included.

Comment: @sterstar [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/7bpJSc), perhaps you're doing something else wrong?

Comment: `while(fgets(day,1024,file)!= NULL && fgets(rese,1024 , file) != NULL){   oken=strtok(day,"/");                                                                     printf("%s\n",oken);
strcpy(res[i].entry,day); i++; }`

Comment: @sterstar `day` is the *date*. It will still be part of the date-string after the call to `strtok`. The "diary entry" that you supposedly want in `res[i].entry` is in `rese` (with your code).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i change my code to `strcpy(res[i].entry, rese)`, when i output the `res[i].entry`, it show me dates instead of the entries.

Comment: That should not happen with the little code snippet you show in the comment, not unless you do something else wrong, or already have gone out of sync from the very beginning *before* the loop. Please take look at my [working example](https://ideone.com/7bpJSc) again. Start with that yourself. Then slowly, and step by step, add the rest of the things you need. And remember to *test* between each and every small step. And of course, [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: the posted code has a couple of problems.  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value from each call to `strtok()`  2) the second line in the file *if the pairs of lines) is not available until the code actually reads it in, for instance by another call to `fgets()

Comment: i have managed to solve the problem but i am getting a segmentation fault when i run my code in Unix. Refer my code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150137/i-get-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-when-i-tried-to-run-program-with-struct

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. performs the desired functionality
2. gives meaningful names to the 'magic' numbers
3. separates the struct definition from the typedef for that struct
4. updated/edited with latest question details

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 1024

struct journal
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    char entry[ MAX_LINE_LEN ];
};
typedef struct journal Diary;


int main( void )
{

    FILE* file=fopen("struct.txt","r");
    if ( !file )
    {
        perror("fopen failed");}
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    char line[ MAX_LINE_LEN ];
    int size;

    if( fgets( line, sizeof line, file ) )
    {
        if ( sscanf( line, "%d", size ) != 1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf for data count failed\m" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, input of data count successful
    }

    else
    {
        perror( "fgets for data count failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fgets successful


    Diary myDiary[ size ];  // uses VLA (variable length array feature of C


    size_t i = 0;
    char *token = NULL;

    while( i < size && fgets( line, sizeof( line ), file) )
    {
        token = strtok( line, "/" );
        if( token )
        {
            myDiary[i].day = atoi( token );

            token = strtok( NULL, "/" );
            if( token )
            {
                myDiary[i].month = atoi( token );

                token = strtok( NULL, "/" );
                if( token )
                {
                    myDiary[i].year = atoi( token );

                    // input data directly into struct instance
                    fgets( myDiary[i].entry, MAX_LINE_LEN, file );
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: do note that the second instance of `fgets()` will include the newline at the end of the `myDiary[i].entry`  You may want to eliminate the newline from being saved by: `myDiary[i].entry[ strspn( myDiarn[i].entry, '\n' )  ] = '\0' ;`

Comment: how about i need to dynamically allocate the struct of arrays? I think that where my problem is. the file that my program has to read, actually the first line contain a single integer which is 4, indicate the size of struct of array. then the subsequent is the journal entries.

Comment: I am able to save my day, month and year into my structure, but storing the strings (entries) is still the problem. I tried to declare char* entries[] to store the entries, but when i want to print it out, my program crashed

Comment: the 'entries' should NOT be an array of pointers to char but rather an array of char

Comment: even so, my program still crashed. i declare `char entries[1024]` and then the second fgets `fgets(&entries[i],1024,file)`. is it correct?

Comment: no, `fgets(&entries[i],1024,file)`  is not correct.   My answer is complete without any changes.  in my answer, the first line is read and broken into the desired fields (day, month, year)  Then the second line is read, directly into an instance of the struct.  the only array that you want to be indexing through is `myDiary[]`  The `myDiary[]` is an array of instances of the typedef Diary, which is a rename of the `struct Journal`.  After both lines are read, increment the index 'i' and repeat the loop until EOF

Comment: i understand your code. but when i write `fgets(myDiary[i].entry,1024,file)` in my code, it crashes as well. i guess it is because previously, i declare `Diary* myDiary =(Diary*)malloc((size)*sizeof(Diary));`, which `size` is 4 as read from the file. this is required by the question

Comment: Please post your latest code and any criteria your code must observe as an edit to your question.

Comment: I see where the contents of the input file now contains a count of the  number of following pairs of lines,  I have modified my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your code. I managed to solve my problem but i am having a segmentation fault when i run in Unix. Refer my code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150137/i-get-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-when-i-tried-to-run-program-with-struct

Comment: after calling: `file = fopen("struct.txt", "r");`  and before calling: `while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)` you need to consume all the white space, especially the newline.  Otherwise the first call to `fgets()` will only read zero or more spaces + the newline.  that is why the first I/O in my answer was a call to `fgets()` so the whole first line will be read into memory.

Comment: in your referenced code, the code block starting with: `while (l < size)
            {
                res[l].day = res2[k].day;`  reads from `res2[]` an entry that was never filled (the last entry being copied reads past the end of the data)  Resulting in undefined behavior.  (why not just write it to `res[]`  initially?)

Comment: in your referenced code: regarding: `choice = atoi(argv[1]);`  validate the value in `choice` to assure it is within the valid range (0...4)  otherwise it will (also) have undefined behavior

Comment: in your referenced code: this statement: ` fclose(file);` is located in the execution path when the call to `fopen()` has failed.  There will be a seg fault event if the `fopen()` failed

Answer (score 0):

Your problem presents the classic problem of "How do I read and allocate for X number of something when I don't know how many beforehand?" This is actually a simpler variant of the question, because you can read the `X` number as the first line from your data file.

(which simplifies the problem to a single allocation of X structs after reading the first line - otherwise you would need to keep track of the current number of structs allocated and `realloc` as required)

To begin, I would recommend against creating `char entry[1024];` within your struct for two reasons - first, the automatic storage for `entry` is created on the stack and a large diary could easily StackOverflow... Second, it's just wasteful. If the goal is dynamic allocation, then allocate only the storage necessary for each `entry`. You can declare a single buffer of `1024` chars to use as a read buffer, but then allocate only `strlen (buf) + 1` char to hold the entry (after trimming the included `'\n'` from the entry).

The remainder of your problem, is the basis for any reliable code, is simply to **validate** each read, each parse, and each allocation so you insure you are processing valid data and have valid storage throughout your code. This applies to every pieces of code you write, not just this problem.

Putting those pieces together, and providing further details inline in the comments below, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct journal {
    int day,
        month,
        year;
    char *entry;    /* declare a pointer, allocate only need No. of chars */
} diary_t;

#define MAXLENGTH 1024  /* max read buf for diary entry */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t entries = 0, i, n = 0;
    char buf[MAXLENGTH] = "";
    diary_t *diary = NULL;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read first line, parse number of entries */
    if (!(fgets (buf, MAXLENGTH, fp)) ||        /* validate read */
        sscanf (buf, "%zu", &entries) != 1) {   /* validate conversion */
        fputs ("error: failed to read 1st line.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate/validate entries number of diary_t */
    if (!(diary = calloc (entries, sizeof *diary))) {
        perror ("calloc-diary_pointers");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < entries; i++) { /* loop No. entries times */

        size_t len = 0;
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXLENGTH, fp)) {  /* read/validate date */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to read date %zu.\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d/%d/%d",    /* parse into day, month, year */
                    &diary[i].day, &diary[i].month, &diary[i].year) != 3) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error failed to parse date %zu.\n", i);
            return 1;
        }

        if (!fgets (buf, MAXLENGTH, fp)) {  /* read entry */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to read entry %zu.\n", i);
            return 1;
        }

        len = strlen (buf);                 /* get length */
        if (len && buf[len - 1] == '\n')    /* check last char is '\n' */
            buf[--len] = 0;                 /* overwrite with nul-character */
        else if (len == MAXLENGTH - 1) {    /* check entry too long */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: entry %zu exceeds MAXLENGTH.\n", i);
            return 1;
        }

        /* allocate/validate memory for entry */
        if (!(diary[i].entry = malloc ((len + 1)))) {
            perror ("malloc-diary_entry");
            fprintf (stderr, "error: memory exausted, entry[%zu].\n", i);
            break;  /* out of memory error, don't exit, just break */
        }
        strcpy (diary[i].entry, buf);   /* copy buf to entry */

        n++;    /* increment successful entry read */
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* output diary entries */
        printf ("entry[%2zu]:  %2d/%2d/%4d - %s\n", i, diary[i].day,
                diary[i].month, diary[i].year, diary[i].entry);
        free (diary[i].entry);  /* don't forget to free entries */
    }
    free (diary);   /* don't forget to free diary */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you can further simplify the code by using POSIX `getline()` for your read instead of a fixed `buf` and you can simplify the allocation and copy of each entry into your struct using `strdup()`, but neither are guaranteed available to all compilers -- use them if your compiler supports them and portability everywhere isn't a concern. Also note the GNU gcc uses `%zu` as the format specifier for `size_t`. If you are on windoze, change each to `%lu`)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/diary.txt
4
12/04/2010
Interview went well I think, though was told to wear shoes.
18/04/2010
Doc advised me to concentrate on something... I forget.
03/05/2010
Was asked today if I was an art exhibit.
19/05/2010
Apparently mudcakes not made of mud, or angry wasps.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/diary <dat/diary.txt
entry[ 0]:  12/ 4/2010 - Interview went well I think, though was told to wear shoes.
entry[ 1]:  18/ 4/2010 - Doc advised me to concentrate on something... I forget.
entry[ 2]:   3/ 5/2010 - Was asked today if I was an art exhibit.
entry[ 3]:  19/ 5/2010 - Apparently mudcakes not made of mud, or angry wasps.
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/diary <dat/diary.txt
==6403== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6403== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6403== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6403== Command: ./bin/diary
==6403==
entry[ 0]:  12/ 4/2010 - Interview went well I think, though was told to wear shoes.
entry[ 1]:  18/ 4/2010 - Doc advised me to concentrate on something... I forget.
entry[ 2]:   3/ 5/2010 - Was asked today if I was an art exhibit.
entry[ 3]:  19/ 5/2010 - Apparently mudcakes not made of mud, or angry wasps.
==6403==
==6403== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6403==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6403==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 309 bytes allocated
==6403==
==6403== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6403==
==6403== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6403== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

(**note:** the storage required for all diary entries (the entire diary) is only `309-bytes` that is less than `1/10th` the storage required declaring `char entry[1024];`)

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

---

**MS Windows**

Since you seem to be having problems on windows, the following is the code above, with nothing but `%lu` substituted for `%zu` (as windows treats `%zu` as a literal), compiled on Win7 with an older version of VS compiler:

```
> cl /?
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

**Compile**

```
> cl /nologo /Wall /wd4706 /wd4996 /Ox /Foobj/diary /Febin/diary /Tc diary.c
```

(**note:** I put my .obj files in a subdirectory `./obj` and my binary executables in `./bin` to keep my source directory clean. That is the purpose of `/Foobj/diary` and `/Febin/diary` above)

**Example Use/Output**

```
> bin\diary.exe dat\diary.txt
entry[ 0]:  12/ 4/2010 - Interview went well I think, though was told to wear shoes.
entry[ 1]:  18/ 4/2010 - Doc advised me to concentrate on something... I forget.
entry[ 2]:   3/ 5/2010 - Was asked today if I was an art exhibit.
entry[ 3]:  19/ 5/2010 - Apparently mudcakes not made of mud, or angry wasps.
```

You must insure you change, each and every `%zu` to `%lu` or you cannot expect proper output. You say you have changed all to `int`, but the snippet you posted in the comments below contains `%zu` -- this will not work on windows.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I get the `error failed to parse date 0`. why is this so?

Comment: Did you copy exactly? That error means your 1st call to `sscanf` within the loop failed. If you copied exactly, the only way that can happen is if your input file is not in the format you provided. You are giving the filename to read as the 1st argument to the program (or are redirecting the file on `stdin` to the program), right?

Comment: I bet you are reading the number with `scanf` and then looping. Reading the first line with `scanf` will leave the trailing `'\n'` in `stdin` and that will cause the read of the date to fail (which is the reason I used `fgets` for the first line, instead of `scanf`)

Comment: i copy exactly the code from the for loop to `if (!fgets (buf, MAXLENGTH, fp)) {  /* read entry */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to read entry %zu.\n", i);
            return 1;
        }` and my input file is exactly the same format i provided. I am not using argument, I just `fopen` the input file and read. I am using `fscanf` to read the number at the first line

Comment: if i am using `fgets` to read the number of entries like the code you provided, my program crashed

Comment: Are you on Windows? Did you read the note about changing all `%zu` to `%lu` (windows doesn't recognize the `%zu` format specifier). Make that change and it will work fine. *"Also note the GNU gcc uses `%zu` as the format specifier for `size_t`. If you are on windoze, change each to `%lu`"* That's all I needed and it will compile without warning or error under Win7 and VS 10.0. When you compile any code, it should compile without warning. Don't accept code until it compiles without a single warning using `/W3` with VS (you can use `/Wall` -- but your will get non-code warnings then)

Comment: i am using Windows, but i am not using `size_t` but i am using `int`, hence i am not using `%zu` but `%d`, i dont see that as a problem. My compiler compiles well without any warning with `/Wall` but it still crashed.

Comment: What do you have in your data file? The code validates every step it takes and gives a descriptive error any where it fails. If it is still exits on `error failed to parse date 0`, then you have a data file problem. I have compiled the code given both on Linux and Windows and it runs without a problem. Are you are mixing `size_t` and `int` in any of the comparisons? Edit your question and ADD (at the end), the code you currently say fails -- and I'll tell you why it is failing.

Comment: From your comment above `... fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to read entry %zu.\n", i);` you still have `%zu` format specifiers in the code. I thought you said you were not using them?

Comment: I have solved the problem but i having segmentation fault when i run it in Unix. Refer my code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150137/i-get-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-when-i-tried-to-run-program-with-struct