# I get segmentation fault (core dumped) when I tried to run program with struct

Tags: c, unix, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I need to read a file and store the data from the file into a structure. The first line of the file contains the size of the array of structs that i have to dynamically allocate.

```
    4
    12/04/2010
    Interview went well I think, though was told to wear shoes.
    18/04/2010
    Doc advised me to concentrate on something... I forget.
    03/05/2010
    Was asked today if I was an art exhibit.
    19/05/2010
    Apparently mudcakes not made of mud, or angry wasps.
```

I am to run my code perfectly in Windows but when I run in Unix environment it shows me segmentation fault (core dumped). I did use `valgrind` to check for the memory leak and that is the results

```
    ==4344== Invalid read of size 1
    ==4344==    at 0x407F842: ____strtol_l_internal (strtol_l.c:298)
    ==4344==    by 0x407F606: strtol (strtol.c:108)
    ==4344==    by 0x407C87E: atoi (atoi.c:27)
    ==4344==    by 0x8048837: main (in /home/admininistrator/ucp/p6/gg)
    ==4344==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
    ==4344== 
    ==4344== 
    ==4344== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
    ==4344==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
    ==4344==    at 0x407F842: ____strtol_l_internal (strtol_l.c:298)
    ==4344==    by 0x407F606: strtol (strtol.c:108)
    ==4344==    by 0x407C87E: atoi (atoi.c:27)
    ==4344==    by 0x8048837: main (in /home/admininistrator/ucp/p6/gg)
    ==4344==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
    ==4344==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
    ==4344==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
    ==4344==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
    ==4344==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
    ==4344== 
    ==4344== HEAP SUMMARY:
    ==4344==     in use at exit: 1,396 bytes in 3 blocks
    ==4344==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 0 frees, 1,396 bytes allocated
    ==4344== 
    ==4344== LEAK SUMMARY:
    ==4344==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==4344==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==4344==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==4344==    still reachable: 1,396 bytes in 3 blocks
    ==4344==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==4344== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
    ==4344== 
    ==4344== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
    ==4344== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here is my code attached

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"struct.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("You have enter less arguments.\n");
    }
    else if (argc > 2)
    {
        printf("You have enter too many arguments.");
    }
    else
    {
        FILE *file;
        Diary *res;
        Diary *res2;
        char line[102];
        int i, size, k, l, choice;
        int day, month, year;
        /* int d[10],m[10],y[10];*/
        char as[102];
        char* oken;
        char* yoken;
        char* coken;
        oken = NULL;
        yoken = NULL;
        coken = NULL;

        i = 0;

        file = fopen("struct.txt", "r");
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error opening file\n.");
        }
        else
        {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &size);
            res = (Diary*) malloc(size * sizeof(Diary));
            res2 = (Diary*) calloc((5), sizeof(Diary));

            while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
            {
                oken = strtok(line, "/");
                if (oken != NULL)
                {
                    res2[i].day= atoi(oken);
                    coken = strtok(NULL, "/");
                    if (oken != NULL)
                    {
                        res2[i].month = atoi(coken);
                        yoken = strtok(NULL, "\n ");
                        if (coken != NULL)
                        {
                            /*printf("%s",yoken);*/
                            res2[i].year = atoi(yoken);

                            fgets(as, 102, file);
                            strncpy(res2[i].entry, as, 102);
                        }
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            k = 1;
            l = 0;

            while (l < size)
            {
                res[l].day = res2[k].day;
                res[l].month = res2[k].month;
                res[l].year = res2[k].year;
                strncpy(res[l].entry, res2[k].entry, 102);
                k++;
                l++;
            }

            choice = atoi(argv[1]);

            printf("%d-%02d-%02d:%s",res[choice].year, res[choice].month,res[choice].day,res[choice].entry);

            free(res2);
            free(res);
        }

        fclose(file);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I need to read all the data from the file to the struct and print it out whenever user want the entry. I tried to debug part by part, and I found out it is the part `while( fgets( line, sizeof( line ), file) != NULL)` that loop, gives the problem. But I have no idea how to fix it.

My `struct.h` is given as below:

```
   typedef struct journal{
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        char entry[1024];
   } Diary;
```

Comment: Start by building with debug information (add the `-g` flag). Then run in a debugger to catch the crash as it happens. Go up the funciton call stack to your code and examine all involved variables and their values.

Comment: as far as I can tell it is a typo twice. you are checking for oken !=NULL twice. Instead you want to check for coken, then for yoken. If you named your variables properly, this wouldnt have happened

Comment: A hint though: Consistency! You call `strtok` a few times, assigning to different variables. And then using *other* variables instead of the ones you assigned from the `strok` call. Like you have `yoken = strtok(...)` and then check `if (coken != NULL)`.

Comment: can you run the program with this flags and add the output <br/> `valgrind --leak-check=full -v app arg arg`

Comment: What is `struct.h`?

Comment: You obviously put some effort in the question, I appreciate that with an upvote. But the formating of your code is a real mess...

Comment: This doesn't meet the standard of a [mcve]. You tried to give enough information, and that's good, but now you should learn a bit on how to narrow down the problem. The first comment will already help you (use `-g` to have debugging information). You might also want to read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), just for some good ideas.

Comment: `i++;` is only conditioned on a successful read of `line` -- not a successful parse of values into `res2` (which you fully omit `res2[i].day` instead you simply `day = atoi(oken);` Further, don't use `atoi` (there is zero error checking). You could have `atoi ("gorilla");` and still get a `0` return. Use `strtol` instead and validate (1) characters were converted; and (2) `errno == 0`. Then after checking `INT_MIN <= val && val <= INT_MAX`  (and that it is within the range of `day, month, year`, you can safely assign the converted value to your final `int` variable.

Comment: Now go copy the code I posted verbatim at [How to get alternative line from a file and store it as string into a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015872/how-to-get-alternative-line-from-a-file-and-store-it-as-string-into-a-struct) and check with `valgrind` again.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings. Take the habit of initializing all pointers to `NULL`. Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and of course `valgrind`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand all of what you are trying to achieve, but here are a few issues.

1. You probably don't need the `day month year` variables.
2. This line

   `day = atoi(oken);`

   should probably be

   `res2[i].day = atoi(oken);`
3. There is a problem with the line that reads the `size`

   `fscanf(file, "%d", &size)`

   This reads an integer **but it does not read the trailing newline**

   You need to change this to be something like

   `fscanf(file, "%d\n", &size)`

   or use `fgets`.

   Because of the trailing newline, the next time you call `gets` you obtain a string containing just the newline.
4. Your `strtok` calls and NULL checks are out of phase. The first one, for `oken` is OK. But then you do a `strtok` returning `coken` but a NULL check on `oken` and lastly a `strtok` returning `yoken` and a NULL check on `coken`. In all 3 cases, the call to `strtok` should be followed by a NULL check on the returned value (as is the case for `oken`).
5. I don't understand the purpose of the `while (l < size)` loop (maybe because of the mishandling of the newline as described above?). You allocate 5 structs, read 4 from structs.txt into `res2` (elements 0 to 3) then you copy elements 1 to 4 of `res2` into elements 0 to 3 of `res`. This means that element 0 of `res2` doesn't get copied and element 4 which is all zeroes does get copied.

The cause of the crash is a combination of points 3 and 4.

I would advise against using `atoi` as it does no error checking. It is unsafe to use unless you are certain that the string contains a well-formed integer. If you want your code to be robust, you need to add more error checking e.g., check the return values of `malloc` and `calloc`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved for my problem and now my program run perfectly!